# ServiceStack JsonServiceClient: SendAsync uses wrong path, ignores Route attribute?

Tags: rest, servicestack

I am using JsonServiceClient in a Xamarin app, like this:

```
JsonServiceClient client = new JsonServiceClient("https://my.domain.com/");
SetHeaders(client);

var request = ...; // this is IRequest<T>
var result = await client.SendAsync(request); // <-- FAILS, can't find service
```

My backend returns an answer, saying that there is no service at that endpoint, which is true, the path that was actually sent over the wire is incorrect.

The `request` is defined in a lib, like so:

```
[Route("/mybasepath/endpoint", "POST")]
public class Login : IReturn<LoginResponse>
{
}
```

The problem is the path that is used in the call, which is wrong and does not follow the Route attribute:

`https://my.domain.com/json/reply/Login`

Here, ServiceStack client uses the default `/json/reply` path, even though I have the `Route` attribute defined in the DTO.

If I change the method used on the `client` instance, and instead use `PostAsync`, the path is ten correct and the call work as expected:

```
JsonServiceClient client = new JsonServiceClient("https://my.domain.com/");
SetHeaders(client);

var request = ...; // this is IRequest<T>
var result = await client.PostAsync(request); // <-- WORKS!
```

I don't have a minimal project right now that can be immediately tested, maybe it is something easy I have missed?

(Using ServiceStack.Client v 5.10.4 on VS 2019 16.9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use ServiceStack's generic `Send*` APIs the Service Clients needs to explicitly infer the Verb to use by annotating the Request DTO with an [HTTP Verb Interface Marker](https://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client#http-verb-interface-markers), not necessary for [AutoQuery](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms) or [AutoQuery CRUD](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-crud) APIs which is inferred from their base classes.

Otherwise `Send*` APIs are designed to fallback to use ServiceStack's [pre-defined Routes](https://docs.servicestack.net/routing#pre-defined-routes).

Comment: Alright, thanks. But... the Route attribute does contain the verb (in string format), this isnt something that could be used, avoiding extra annotations? =)

Comment: @Ted The Routes don't say what the client should use, only what custom User-defined routes are available for that Request DTO. The combination of what Verb the Request is sent with + what Request DTO properties are populated are what's used to find the best matching user-defined route to use (when matches are available).